# Use OptaPlanner directly from another Script (without API)

Tags: optaplanner

is it for using OptaPlanner required, that the tool is available with a domain as example www.apioptaplanner.com, or is it also possible to use the features directly from another script?

Comment: What do you mean with _another script_? What do you mean with that non-existing url?

Comment: Hi,

I have an application (with this i mean "another script") on my server and i need to do requests to optaplanner which is on same server like the application. The usual way to use the api is in this flow:
I send a JSON request to an URL (Domain/IP) and get a JSON respond:
[URL] --JSON-->[OptaPlanner]--JSON-->

But I want to do this:
I send a JSON request directly to the OptaPlanner script (without the API and without the Domain/IP) and get a JSON respond:
[App] --JSON-->[OptaPlanner]--JSON-->

Comment: If it is on the same server, can't you do a CLI invocation with the appropriate arguments to pass the file ?

Comment: I don't know if CLI is working. Do you know that?